# Firebase: Create New Object With Push and Then Push to it Simultaneously

Tags: javascript, firebase

Tools: Vanilla Firebase and Vanilla JavaScript

So I'm creating a new convo and adding it's first message in one go.

```
convos:{
    uniqueConvoID1:{
        uniqueMessage:{
          text:"Hi Gus"
        },
        ...
    },
    ...
}
```

**But because both need a unique Id I essentially need to do two pushes simultaneously**.One creates the new object (like `uniqueConvoID1)`, and then creates a new message inside like (`uniqueMessageId`).

I've tried creating an empty object first and then pushing the message but I don't think creating an empty object first is valid.

**Question:
  How do I then initialize an object within an object where both objects need a unique key?**

What I tried:(I pushed a new message and got the convo back.)

```
var newConvoIDRef =  firebaseConvosRef.push({
    authorName: 'Nick',
    text:"Hey!How you been?",
    timestamp: Date.now() - 99999
 });
```

Which created this in the Dashboard:

```
-convos
     - -K2111111111111111 //unique convo id
         -authorName:"Nick"
         -text:"Hey! How have you been?"
         -timestamp:1446866141625
```

But what I need to initial the new convo this way:

```
 -convos
     - -K2111111111111111 unique convo id
         - -K222444444444444 unique message id
             -authorName:"Nick"
             -text:"Hey! How have you been?"
             -timestamp:1446866141625
```

Comment: Instead of describing what you tried, can you share the code of that attempt? See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Yeah sure! Doing it now.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen added what I did. Not sure how much it will help, but I can't think of anything to describe it better. To initialize a new convo I need to create a new object {} and also but a message in it {{message}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're seriously overcomplicating things. Firebase creates paths automatically as you add new values. So this will create the entire chain:

```
var convosRef = new Firebase('https://yours.firebaseio.com/convos');
var convRef = convosRef.push();
var msgRef = convRef.push();

msgRef.set({
    authorName: 'Nick',
    text:"Hey!How you been?",
    timestamp: Date.now() - 99999
 });
```

Note: Firebase also cleans paths up automatically when all values under them are removed. So you can remove the entire branch of the tree, by:

```
msgRef.remove();
```

Comment: Thank you. It seemed like something that should be easy. I tried this last night convosRef.push({}) to initialize and that caused an error before I could push the message. Also read that you couldn't push empty data so I got really confused.

Comment: I hope the docs say that `push(null)` is the same as deleting the data at that location. But it's more important to realize that paths are just strings. The Firebase server doesn't create anything for the two `push()` operations in my snippet, it doesn't even know of them. Only when we `set()` our value, it hears of the entire path and creates what is necessary.